# What is this substance on my golden pathos’ soil?

Tags: soil, bugs, mold

I noticed some really small white bugs made their home in my golden pathos’ soil. i did some research and i think they might be whiteflies or soil mites but i’m hoping for the latter. They are extremely small i couldn’t even get a picture they are like the size of a grain of salt maybe slightly bigger.I’m not sure if this is the cause of the substance but i’d like to know what the stuff is. it’s growing all around the inside of the pot as well.

[image: yellow orange substance]